# How can I make TextField in Javafx to look as beautiful as Android or material UI

Tags: android, css, javafx, scenebuilder, scene

how can I make this type of window in javafx? 
look at the textfield in the image below..

[image]

I finally found Jphonex framework to display like this. But if I generate a **Jar** file and when I try to open that on another computer, it shows error. That computer has java installed in it. **But why isn't it working when I used jPhonex?** It worked for normal Fields.

Comment: Try http://www.jfoenix.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field on your image is part of  [Material Design Spec](https://material.io/guidelines/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-layout).

Use Material Design framework such as [Gluon Mobile](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/4.4.1/#_charm_glisten) or [JFoenix](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix) to make your text field comply with that look and feel.

Comment: thank u. found some videos in youtube that helped :)

Answer (score -1):

Use [TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html) for this kinds of view